# "an idea ___ what I need to do"? (How to fill in the blank)

Tags: prepositions, word-request

What sort of linking word should I use in the following sentence:

> "I thought you might have an idea ___ what I need to do"?

I have always thought that the best linking word in the above sentence would be "on" but now I'm having second thoughts. Is "on" an appropriate linking word to use here? and if it is, is it the only appropriate one to use?

Comment: "Of" is the most common preposition, followed by "about".

Comment: Other possibilities are *concerning* and *regarding*. Or even *with respect to*. I would say that *on* is one of the least common words used in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"About", "for", and "as to" are also usable in this context.  "About" and "as to" are synonyms for "regarding", which [avitus27](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/96028) suggested.  "For" has connotations of a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context and how formal you want to be, 'of' (being standard) or 'regarding' (more formal) would fit.